# How do I save my model when using multiple GPUs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

When I was training on 1 GPU I would call `model.save('test.model')` and I would have a file at the end of my training called `test.model` that I could then use in a prediction code.

Now I am training on 2 GPUs and when I call `model.save('test_2gpus.model')`, I get a folder called `test_2gpus.model`. Within this folder are 2 other folders called: `assets` and `variables`, and one other file called `saved_model.pb`. The `assets` older is empty and the `variables` folder has 3 files in it: `variables.data-00000-of-00002`, `variables.data-00001-of-00002`, and `variables.index`.

**Do I have to save my model differently when using more than 1 GPU?**

**Am I supposed to get a `.model` file or am I supposed to get that folder? If I am supposed to get that folder then how do I load that folder?**

*Using tensorflow version 2.0.0

*Using `import tensorflow.keras as keras`

Comment: Which version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: I am using tensorflow version 2.0.0

Comment: This appears to be a file permission problem, not a problem with multi-GPU.

Answer (score -1):

> Do I have to save my model differently when using more than 1 GPU?

Refer to the tutorial here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/save_and_load

No, you can save it with `model.save(path)`, then load with `tf.keras.models.load_model(path)`.

> Am I supposed to get a .model file or am I supposed to get that folder? If I am supposed to get that folder then how do I load that folder?

You are supposed to get a folder, and then you load by referring to that folder.

```py
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = ... # build model
    model.compile()

folder = "test_2gpus.model"
model.save(folder)
model_loaded = tf.keras.models.load_model(folder)
```

---

If you get an `unknown loss` error, it is because the model is being compiled on load. `tf.keras.models.load_model` has a keyword argument `compile` which is `True` by default. To get around the error, set `compile=False`, and then in the `model.compile` call, set your loss. Keep in mind you do not need to compile if you only want to predict with your model.

Comment: When I try to load the model I get the error `ValueError: Unknown loss function:dice_coef_loss`. When I add `strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`
`with strategy.scope():` then try to load the model I get the error `FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable conv3d/kernel_28217 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/conv3d/kernel_28217/class tensorflow::Var does not exist. [Op:ReadVariableOp]`

Comment: please see my edits for `unknown loss` errors. i'm not sure what's causing the second error. can you update your question with that info? or submit a new question

Comment: Thought I commented why it was incorrect. I am not supposed to get a folder when saving with `MirroredStrategy()`. When I load the folder and print the model summary it shows that it is missing parameters. When I call `model.save(test.model)` with a single gpu that works fine but with `MirroredStrategy()` it should be `model.save(test.h5)` to save my model to a single file. I spent days looking for bugs in my code because you said I was supposed to get a folder instead of a file.

Comment: You will get a folder when saving with `model.save`, unless you provide a filename with the `.h5` extension. `MirroredStrategy` does not affect this. If you want to save to a single file, then use `.h5`. This is in the documentation for [tf.keras.Model.save](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save).